# How to know when SwiftUI keyboard search button tapped in .searchable search window

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, searchable

I am using the .searchable modifier in SwiftUI.  Is there anyway to know when the user presses the search key on the keyboard?
I know how to do this by using a UIViewRepresentable and searchController.  I'm wondering if there is a SwiftUI way of doing it with the .searchable modifier

Answer (score 5):

Add an .onSubmit(of: .search) modifier. Like this:

```
    List {
        ForEach(results, id: \.self) { result in
           Text(result)
        }
    }
    .searchable(text: $searchText)
    .onSubmit(of: .search) {
     // Search button tapped. Perform operation here
    }
```

If if works for you, mark as correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is still beta in macOS 12 (but not i/iPad/tvOS 15) as I write this so not really for this forum, however...

searching has an instance property:

`var isSearching: Bool { get }`

which can be passed into a child view using:

`@Environment(\.isSearching) var isSearching`

and subsequently interrogated from that `var`

Look up the [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/environmentvalues/issearching?changes=_6)

Comment: This is a great solution! I had to move my `List` into its own View to access `@Environment(\.isSearching)`, but this functionality was worth it